# SchemaExport, NHibernate and deleting foreign keys

Tags: nhibernate, schemaexport

I am building my mapping and then using schema export to update my DB. However, if I delete an association in my mapping, since it's no longer in the mapping, when I run SchemaExport, it will not delete the foreign key for the deleted association. This means that it then fails to drop the table associated with that foreign key. Which further means that it can't recreate the table and I get a "There is already an object named Foo in the database" exception. Is there any way to brute delete the table via Schema Export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is to do SchemaExport.Drop with the old nhibernate configuration, then create with the new one.

Alternatively you could drop and recreate the database itself, here's an example which does this at file level for SQL Server Express: http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2010/01/integration-testing-with-sql-server-express-2008-nhibernate-and-mstest/